# Spark CombineByKey

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark RDD in the below format

Sample RDD:

```
Array[(String, (String, Double))] = Array(
       (2014-01-12 00:00:00.0,("XXX",829.95)), 
       (2013-08-28 00:00:00.0,("YYY",469.95000000000005)), 
       (2013-11-01 00:00:00.0,("ZZZ",129.99)), 
       (2013-07-25 00:00:00.0,("XYZ",879.8599999999999)), 
       (2013-10-19 00:00:00.0,
       ("POI",989.94))
)
```

I am trying to use combineByKey to sum the Double values for the given key from the RDD and trying with below command

```
rdd.combineByKey(
  (x:String,y:Double) => (x,y),
  (acc:(String, Double), v:(String, Double)) => acc._2  + v._2, 
  (acc2:(Double), acc3:(Double)) => (acc2 + acc3)
)
```

but getting the below error....

```
 <console>:46: error: overloaded method value combineByKey with
 alternatives:   [C](createCombiner: ((String, Double)) => C,
 mergeValue: (C, (String, Double)) => C, mergeCombiners: (C, C) =>
 C)org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, C)] <and>   [C](createCombiner:
 ((String, Double)) => C, mergeValue: (C, (String, Double)) => C,
 mergeCombiners: (C, C) => C, numPartitions:
 Int)org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, C)] <and>   [C](createCombiner:
 ((String, Double)) => C, mergeValue: (C, (String, Double)) => C,
 mergeCombiners: (C, C) => C, partitioner:
 org.apache.spark.Partitioner, mapSideCombine: Boolean, serializer:
 org.apache.spark.serializer.Serializer)org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,
 C)]  cannot be applied to ((String, Double) => (String, Double),
 ((String, Double), (String, Double)) => Double, (Double, Double) =>
 Double)
               custMaxOrdr.combineByKey((x:String,y:Double) => (x,y) ,(acc:(String,Double),valu:(String,Double)) => acc._2+valu._2,
 (acc2:(Double),acc3:(Double)) => (acc2+acc3))
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks
Rammy

Answer (score 3):

The types of the functions you're passing do not match the expected types. Let's look at the signature of `combineByKey`:

```
def combineByKey[C](
  createCombiner: V => C,
  mergeValue: (C, V) => C,
  mergeCombiners: (C, C) => C): RDD[(K, C)]
```

So, you need to supply:

- Type `C`: The type of the expected combined result, in your case I'm assuming it's `Double`. Of course, this type can be inferred by the compiler if not supplied explicitly
- `createCombiner: V => C`: In our case, a function of type `(String, Double) => Double`; You're passing `(x:String,y:Double) => (x,y)`, which has a different type; Per your description, I assume you just want this function to extract the `Double` from the tuple, so you'd need: `(in: (String, Double)) => in._2`
- `mergeValue: (C, V) => C`: In our case that would `((String, Double), Double) => Double`, which again does not match the function you supplied which has the type `((String,Double), (String,Double)) => Double`
- `mergeCombiners: (C, C) => C` which in our case would be `(Double, Double) => Double` - here your function matches

Altogether, this would sum the double values per key:

```
val result: RDD[(String, Double)] = rdd.combineByKey(
  (in: (String, Double)) => in._2,
  (acc: Double, valu: (String, Double)) => acc + valu._2,
  (acc2: Double, acc3: Double) => acc2 + acc3
)
```

All functions can be written omitting the types:

```
val result2: RDD[(String, Double)] = rdd.combineByKey(
  _._2,
  (acc, valu) => acc + valu._2,
  (acc2, acc3) => acc2 + acc3
)
```

Comment: Glad it helps :) please upvote/accept the answer to let other users know this is solved.